# Aggregate a table by applying a function of multiple columns

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, aggregate

Considering the following table `df`, with categorical variables noted `x1` and `x2` and numerical measurements noted `y1`, `y2` and `y3`:

```
df <- data.frame(x1=sample(letters[1:3], 20, replace=TRUE),
           x2=sample(letters[4:6], 20, replace=TRUE),
           y1=rnorm(20), y2=rnorm(20), y3=rnorm(20))
```

I'd like to apply on it a function of the 3 numerical measurements `y` with respect to the categorical variables `x`. For example the following function, where the input `y` is a table of 3 columns, which should output one new column:

```
f <- function(y){   sum((y[,1] - y[,2]) / y[,3]) }
```

I tried it with `aggregate`, `dplyr`, `summarizeBy`.. without success as it seems that for every method, mixing the inputs columns is not an option. Any idea on how to do that with such kind of functions (i.e. taking advantage of aggregation)?

```
aggregate(data = df, y1 + y2 + y3 ~ x1 + x2, FUN = f)
```

To clarify, the expected result can be obtained with something like:

```
groups <- unique(df[,c("x1", "x2")]) # coocurences of explanatory variables
res <- c()
for (i in 1:nrow(groups)){ # get the subtables
  temp <- df[df$x1 == groups[i,1] & df$x2 == groups[i,2], c("y1", "y2", "y3")]
  res <- c(res, f(temp)) # apply function on subtables
}
groups$res <- res # aggregate results
```

Which is not that fat for this simple toy example but very impractical with more complex data.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Maybe just `df %>% group_by(x1, x2) %>% summarise(sum_y = sum((y1 - y2) / y3))`?

Comment: @Jaap Yes, that is the idea. Though I'm still unable to use your construction with the `f` function defined above. Could you help me with that ? Trouble is the real `f` function I need to apply is way more complex than the example shown here and cannot be reduced as easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is on th input side of your function. The way you specified it, it expects a dataframe.

A possible slution is to feed the function a list of columns. With a small change to your function:

```
f <- function(y) sum((y[[1]] - y[[2]]) / y[[3]])
```

You can now use it in a `dplyr`-chain:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(x1, x2) %>% 
  summarise(sum_y = f(list(y1, y2, y3)))
```

which gives:

> ```
> # A tibble: 9 x 3
> # Groups:   x1 [?]
>   x1    x2     sum_y
>   <fct> <fct>  <dbl>
> 1 a     d      1.20 
> 2 a     e      0.457
> 3 a     f     -9.46 
> 4 b     d     -1.11 
> 5 b     e     -0.176
> 6 b     f     -1.34 
> 7 c     d     -0.994
> 8 c     e      3.38 
> 9 c     f     -2.63
> ```